# error occurs when reading xlsx file in with android, kotlin, apache poi

Tags: android, excel, kotlin, apache-poi

using kotlin, android, apache poi, I'm trying to read xlsx file.
but error below occurs at the line "WorkbookFactory.create(file)".
does anyone know how to fix it?

and now it can output Excel file, so I guess build.gradle setting is correct.

"ERROR"
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.jpwingsnikkeibpomikuji, PID: 13735
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

```
・・・・

 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

・・・・

 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.<init>(Locale.java:3397)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$XmlReaderSaxLoader.<init>(Locale.java:3087)

・・・・

 Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler

・・・・
```

"source"

"kt file"

```
・・・・
 fun excelToroku(view: View){
     verifyStoragePermissions(this)
     
     val uploadPath: String = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath()
     val file = Paths.get(uploadPath + File.separator + "torokutest.xlsx").toFile()
     
     Log.d("MyApp", file.exists().toString())          <--- true
     val book:Workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file)  <--- here error occurs

・・・・
```

"build.gradle"

```
・・・・
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.2'
    implementation  "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.2"
    implementation 'javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0'
    
・・・・
```

Comment: There is probably some more data that is the stacktrace that you need to post. Something is happening with the sax parser.

Comment: could you try adding apache xerces 2.12.0 to your classpath?

Comment: this is fixed by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XMLBEANS-542 -- I'm not sure if XMLBeans 4.0.0 will work with POI 4.1.2 (which was built with XMLBeans 3.1.0) -- but you could try upgrading POI to 5.0.0